# Android google map - get map click location when marker clicked

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've got a map with plenty of large custom markers on it. Now I want to allow the user to create a path on the map (displayed as polyline and later saved as a list of geocoordinate pairs).

If the user clicks on the map I can collect these positions with the [setOnMapClickedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnMapClickListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener%29) method of the map. But if the user clicks on a marker ([setOnMarkerClickedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnMarkerClickListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener%29)), I can only retrieve the markers position (generally the position of the ancor of the marker).

Is it possible to somehow retrieve the clicked map location when actually a marker was clicked?

I'm using the SupportMapFragment.

Comment: I need this to calculate the correct marker myself, as onMarkerClick event gives me a wrong marker when there are another maker near the clicked marker.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bit late. But i hope this may help you.

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

           Toast.makeText(
                                YourActivity.this,
                                "Lat : " + latLng.latitude + " , "
                                        + "Long : " + latLng.longitude,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(RegActivity.this);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                LatLng position = marker.getPosition();

                Toast.makeText(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                "Lat " + position.latitude + " "
                                        + "Long " + position.longitude,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You didn't read the question correctly. I do NOT need the position of the marker. I need the LatLng position of the click (even if a marker was pressed).

Answer (score 0):

```
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener {
            val  position=p0.cameraPosition.target
            Toast.makeText(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                "Lat " + position.latitude + " "
                                        + "Long " + position.longitude,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();"
    return True
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).